# Convert Function into Spherical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$z=\sqrt{4-x^2-2y^2} $$

First thing I did was put the equation in standard form: $z^2+x^2+2y^2=4 $

Then I convert to spherical: $$\rho^2\cos^2(\phi)+\rho^2\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\theta)+2\rho^2\sin^2(\phi)\sin^2(\theta)=4$$
then I simplify:
$$\rho^2[\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\theta)+2\sin^2(\phi)\sin^2(\theta)]=4$$

How do I simplify from here? As my answer has to be one among the following:

[image]

Comment: Just a side note: the answer should include the condition $\cos \phi\ge 0$, otherwise we can get negative values of $z$, which are prohibited by the equation on $z$. The answer (c) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your last line, it should be
$$\rho^2[\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\left[\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta]\right]=4$$
so that 
$$\rho^2[\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\left(1+\sin^2\theta)\right]=4$$
$$\rho^2(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta)=4$$
$$\rho^2\left((\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)+\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta\right)=4$$
or
$$\rho^2(1+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi)=4$$

Comment: How do you get cos to go to 1? then how that = to the last equation?

Comment: make sense now?

Comment: Yes, tat make more sense, thank you